# python compare set and dict

Tags: python, dictionary, set

I have some DB data1, and when fetchall looks like this..

```
{u'name': 'abcd', u'id': 3}
{u'name': 'efg', u'id': 5}
{u'name': 'xyz', u'id': 6}
```

and i have another data2, not from DB.

and it looks like `set(['abc', 'abdc', 'bcd'])`

I want to find data2 is exist in data1' name and want to return `u'id'`number, if exist

Is there way to find in Python? like using c++ std::map...something like below

```
map<string,int> data1
list<string> data2

map<string,int>::iterator it = data1.find(data2.front());
if (it != data1.end()) {
    std::cout << it->second <<\n;
}
```

my python code below

```
data1 = connect()
data2 = set([])
namelist = set(['abc', 'abdc', 'bcd'])
for row in data1:
    data2.add(row['name'])

find = set([])
find = data2.intersection(data2)
print(find)
# want to print id value
```

Comment: You don't seem to have a tuple anywhere; only a dict and a set.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post your code.

Comment: I think you have more of a `vector <map<string,int>>` than a `map<string, int>` (just guessing at C++ typing).... so it is unclear exactly what you are dealing with, since your python example isn't a valid Python literal, but I can only assume it is a list of dictionaries from context.

Comment: i edited my post , added my python code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is:

```
for elem in data2:
    try:
        print(data1[elem])
    except KeyError:
        pass
```

Or maybe not even a loop, because your C++ code is just taking the first element of a list:

```
elem = data2[0]
try:
    print(data1[elem])
except KeyError:
    pass
```

Or, since you mentioned a set, and C++ sets are sorted by default (Python sets are in arbitrary order, so if you want the smallest value, you have to ask for it), maybe this:

```
elem = min(data2)
try:
    print(data1[elem])
except KeyError:
    pass
```

Comment: thanks for answer and i edit my post, i think first one is my case